# AI optimization algorithms for Subset Sum

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I've been messing around with some AI optimization algorithms for the Subset Sum problem.

I've looked at particle swarm optimization and genetic algorithms.

I know that GA is initially a discrete technique that is also suitable for combinatorial problems, and PSO is a continuous technique that is very poorly suited to combinatorial problems.

This is odd since Subset-Sum is combinatorial but my PSO implementation performs better.

Is there any other reasonably straight-forward algorithms I could try out for solving Subset-Sum?

Comment: These approaches are heuristic by nature and very dependent on additional metaparameters. OF course they are hard to compare. Without a huge well-designed benchmark it's hard to do. Mathematical-programming and Dynamic-programming approaches should both be more powerful as they are using more of the given structure. It's such a well-known problem that you should find a lot of info on wikipedia & google scholar. A side-note: i would not really call this approaches AI, but general optimization approaches. But that's my opinion.

Comment: Thank you. In this case Dynamic Programming will not work as it requires a small s value.

Comment: Well you did not give any information about your instance sizes. The good thing is: it's in general considered as one of the easiest np-hard problems. But maybe not easy enough for your setting. Give a naive MIP-formulation a chance. One more advantage is, that the algorithm is complete. It eiher finds a solution (giving infinite time) or proof it's not possible.